# Why is the $x$ axis for a histogram labeled "bin"?

Tags: terminology, histogram

When talking about histograms, why do we refer to the x-axis as "bin"?

Comment: In vernacular English, a "bin" is a container for holding things.  On the horizontal axis, we have a number bins, each of which holds data points that are sufficiently similar.  We are essentially sorting the data into box.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bin+statistics+histogram&oq=bin+statistics+histogram

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When wanting to create a histogram of a continuous variable, you first need to split those into **bins** (sometimes referred to as **buckets**). Subsequently, this procedure is called [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) or bucketing.

So the x-axis of a histogram represents the bins of the continuous variable.

Comment: You could also bin discrete/count data, in whole or in part. For example, number of sexual partners often has a long right tail that researchers top code at X+.  Histogram construction is largely a tradeoff
between detail and generalization (or variance and bias), and this tradeoff does not depend on the type of data.

Comment: Yes you are correct, binning works on discrete data as well, however I wanted to point out that you can't have a histogram from a continuous variable without binning it first.